# Disaggregating Data Using SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have 3 tables:

**Table 1:**

| Column A | Column B | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 5.455626797 |
| A1 | B2 | 4.474291714 |
| A2 | B1 | 9.96811376 |
| A2 | B2 | 5.462867002 |

**Table 2:**

| Column A | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | C1 | 3.313957532 |
| A1 | C2 | 6.615960979 |
| A2 | C1 | 9.782949121 |
| A2 | C2 | 5.648031641 |

**Table 3:**

| Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | C1 | 10.76037672 |
| B1 | C2 | 4.663363842 |
| B2 | C1 | 2.336529937 |
| B2 | C2 | 7.600628779 |

How can I use these 3 tables to deaggregate the data back into it's original form. RAW Data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 1.41704499 |
| A1 | B1 | C2 | 4.038581807 |
| A1 | B2 | C1 | 1.896912542 |
| A1 | B2 | C2 | 2.577379172 |
| A2 | B1 | C1 | 9.343331726 |
| A2 | B1 | C2 | 0.6247820347 |
| A2 | B2 | C1 | 0.4396173952 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | 0.4396173952 |

I tried using some generic disaggregating queries, but column D was never accurately disaggregated.

Examples:

1)

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t2.C, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t3.C IS NULL THEN t1.D - t2.D 
    WHEN t1.B = t2.C THEN 0 
    ELSE t1.D + t3.D - t2.D 
  END AS D
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.B = t3.B AND t2.C = t3.C
ORDER BY A, B, C;
```

2. 

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t2.C, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t3.C IS NULL THEN t1.D - t2.D 
    WHEN t1.B = t2.C THEN COALESCE(t3.D, 0)
    ELSE t1.D + COALESCE(t3.D, 0) - t2.D 
  END AS D
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON (t1.B = t3.B AND t2.C = t3.C) OR (t1.B = t2.C)
ORDER BY A, B, C;
```

Comment: I don't think you can manage to get the original values by adding or subtracting. It looks like you should craft the system of equations.

Comment: Hi - so what is the logic/rules for calculating column D in the results?

Comment: @MarcoMerola would you happen to have some snippet SQL or python code that could help me create the system of equations?

Comment: @NickW column D is summed up to get the values you see in Table 1, Table 2, and Table 3

Comment: @ArhamAbidi unfortunately I am not able to craft the mathematical equations to reconstruct the original values from the aggregated ones. I guess there is more math than sql behind this problem haha. Keep in mind that it's not always fully possible to reverse the aggregations and retrive the original values.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn’t clear, I was asking how you calculated column D in your resultset not how you calculated column D in tables 1,2,3 that you are starting with

Comment: @NickW actually, the resulting table is the original dataset, and tables 1,2,3 are aggregations of subsets of columns. I want to know if I can reverse this aggregation.